# How to find empty fields in json file?

Tags: python, json, string, integer

I have this `sample.json` file with me:

```
{   
    "details":[
    {
    "name": "",
    "class": "4",
    "marks": "72.6"
    },
    {
    "name": "David",
    "class": "",
    "marks": "78.2"
    },
    {
    "name": "Emily",
    "class": "4",
    "marks": ""
    }
    
    
]
}
```

As you can see for the first one; `"name"` is string datatype is actually empty.
For the second one; `"class"` with integer datatype is empty.
And for the third one; `"marks"` with float datatype is empty.

Now my task is;
to find the fields which are empty, if string is empty replace it with "BLANK", if integer is empty replace it with 0, and if float is empty replace it with 0.0

P.S: I'm doing this with Python like this:

```
import json
path = open('D:\github repo\python\sample.json')
df = json.load(path)
for i in df["details"]:
    print(i["name"])
```

Also make sure that I don't want to hard-code the values. Coz here if we see there are only 3 fields(name, class, marks) but what if I have more that 3. Then what? How will I find which fields are empty or not?

Like you see here:

```
{
    "code": "AAA",
    "lat": "-17.3595",
    "lon": "-145.494",
    "name": "Anaa Airport",
    "city": "Anaa",
    "state": "Tuamotu-Gambier",
    "country": "French Polynesia",
    "woeid": "12512819",
    "tz": "Pacific\/Midway",
    "phone": "",
    "type": "Airports",
    "email": "",
    "url": "",
    "runway_length": "4921",
    "elev": "7",
    "icao": "NTGA",
    "direct_flights": "2",
    "carriers": "1"
  },
```

This is just one block, I've N-number of blocks like this. That's why I can't hard_code the values right?

Can anybody help me with it!

Thank You so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since the type info isn't available anywhere programmatically, and there seem to be only three hard-coded fields, I'd just check each of them explicitly.

Short-circuiting with the `or` operator would even allow you to achieve this fairly elegantly:

```py
for d in df['details']:
    d['name'] = d['name'] or 'BLANK'
    d['class'] = d['class'] or '0'
    d['marks'] = d['marks'] or '0.0'
```

Comment: But what if there are N-number of records there! Then how will I check it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check whether the string is empty with a simple if statement like so.

`if not i['name'] == ""`

Alternatively, you could also do

`if not i['name']`

The second if statement makes use of falsy and truthy values in Python. Here's a [link](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/) to read more about it

Comment: What if there are more records/fields and not just 3! Then how will I check it?

Comment: You could make use of the dictionary, as answered by Rafiq above.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a dictionary `empty_replacements` mapping each key to its corresponding desired empty value:

```
import json

sample_json = {
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "",
            "class": "4",
            "marks": "72.6"
        },
        {
            "name": "David",
            "class": "",
            "marks": "78.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Emily",
            "class": "4",
            "marks": ""
        }
    ]
}

empty_replacements = {"name": "BLANK", "class": "0", "marks": "0.0"}

sample_json["details"] = [{
    k: v if v else empty_replacements[k]
    for k, v in d.items()
} for d in sample_json["details"]]

print('sample_json after replacements: ')
print(json.dumps(
    sample_json,
    sort_keys=False,
    indent=4,
))
```

**Output:**

```
sample_json after replacements:
{
    "details": [
        {
            "name": "BLANK",
            "class": "4",
            "marks": "72.6"
        },
        {
            "name": "David",
            "class": "0",
            "marks": "78.2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Emily",
            "class": "4",
            "marks": "0.0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: What if there are more records/fields and not just 3! Then how will I check it? – 
@PratikBawane

Comment: How did you get the output in that systematic format? Coz I'm working in jupyter notebook and I'm getting a list here! Any idea how can I reframe it?

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow? `sample_json` should be still a dictionary even in a Jupyter notebook! `json.dumps` is just used for pretty-printing! `sample_json["details"]` is a list and that is the thing we are modifying?

Answer (score 0):

I 'm assuming by the dictionary which you provided that marks & class are stored as String.

```
li=[]
for d in df["details"]:
    for k,v in d.items():
        if (v==''):
            if (k=='name'):
                d[k]="BLANK"
            elif (k=='class') :
                d[k]='0'
            elif (k=='marks'):
                d[k]='0.0'
    li.append(d)
df['details']=li
```